# Ajax form content and insert into DB with Laravel ..

Tags: ajax, laravel-5

i created a form using AJAX because i have several alternatives concerning the fields.

I have correct information in my javascript and make tests... my first select use the following function and generates form

```
function setParentSector() {
    $("#listSectors").html("");
    $("#createSector").html("");

    if($('#langname option:selected').val() !=0) {
        var obj = { 'id': $('#langname option:selected').val() };
        if (obj['id'] != 1) {
            ajaxSectors(obj);
        }
        else
        {
            // another form generated here ... 
            $('#createSector').append("something else");
        }
    }
};
```

I use a "classical" ajax ..

```
function ajaxSectors(objSetParent) {  
    $.ajax({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        },
        url: '/admin/ajax/sectorParent',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: true,
        success: function (result) {

            $('#listSectors').append("<label for='langname'>label </label> " +
                "<select class='form-control m-input m-input--air' id='sectors' onclick='setLangTranslation()'>" +
                "<option value='0' selected>Select value</option></select>" +
                "<span class='m-form__help' id='existsAlready'>");
            var count = result.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            if (result[i].deleted_at === null) {
                $('#sectors').append("<option value='" + result[i].sector_id  + "'>" + result[i].sectname + "</option>");
                }
                else {
                    console.log("peanuts");
                }

            }
        },
        data:objSetParent,
        error: function (result) {
        },
        complete: function (result) {
        //console.log("complete");
        }
    });
}
```

This part of code works fine and i display what i want... 
When I want to save into DB the form, I plan to use the store method and I create the $request->validate()

In the store method I have :

```
$request->validate([
    'admin' => 'required',
    'langname'  => 'required',
    'sectname' => 'required',
    'sectshortname' => 'nullable',
 ]);

 return view ('test')
```

The test view contains just  in order to see what i post ..

If i keep the validate part, the page is just refreshed and not validated... 
Without the request validate I display the view and i just see the value of the input with the token.

Thanks for your answers. Let's hope my question is "clear" enough

Answer (score 0):

Use this code I hope  this code works for you please use this  `Use Validator;`

```
   $rules = [
    'admin' => 'required',
    'langname'  => 'required',
    'sectname' => 'required',
    'sectshortname' => 'nullable',
   ];

   $data = $request->all();//or you can get it by one by one
   $validator = Validator::make($data , $rules);
   if ($validator->fails()) {
        $error=[];

        $errors = $validator->messages();

        foreach($errors->all() as $error_msg){
            $error[]= $error_msg;
        }           
        return response()->json(compact('error'),401);
    }
   return view ('test')
```